# Issue connection to MySQL through jDBC with saiku

Tags: mysql, jdbc, saiku

This is my file connections:

```
type=OLAP
name=ghapBI
driver=mondrian.olap4j.MondrianOlap4jDriver
location=jdbc:mondrian:Jdbc=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/ghapBI;Catalog=/opt/django/bi_data/SchemaGHAP.xml;JdbcDrivers=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;
username=usrGhapBI
password=hiperSecret
```

Connection are made but an exception appears (from catalina.out ):

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
SELECT command denied to user 'usrGhapBI'@'localhost' for table 'alumnes'
```

Notice than:

- error is the same if I drop de table.
- I can connect and select data from this table from `mysql -u usrGhapBI -p ghapBI`

I miss something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open catalog file, in your case: `/opt/django/bi_data/SchemaGHAP.xml` and check for right schema in table definition:

```
<Table name="alumnes" schema="**** check here ****" alias="">
```